# how to stop or reduce the RAM usage as the Wpf Datagrid is Continuosly being updated by background Worker

Tags: wpf, memory, datagrid, backgroundworker

I am developing a packet sniffer application, I am getting a packets from adapter and am updating the information in the Wpf Datagrid using a Background Worker. it is a continuous process. So if run this application for hours, after 5 or 6 hours I am getting a "Sytem.OutofMemoryException" as the RAM being full. Now my requirement is, the usage of RAM should have a some limit(suppose 750MB) for my application, once application reaches this, the usage of RAM should not increase and at the same time I should not get "OutofmemoryException". I mean application should free cached memory of starting Rows of DataGrid, means I should not display the initial Rows and I should display the latest entries. how can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** I am using Items.Add() method. I am continuously appending the data using background worker.

```
void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        int i = e.ProgressPercentage;
        packetinformation packinfo1 = new packetinformation();
        packinfo1 = (packetinformation)e.UserState;
        Packet_add_Datagrid(packinfo1,i);
    }


 public void Packet_add_Datagrid(packetinformation packinfo1,int i)
    {datagrid1.Items.Add(new test() { sno = i + 1, name = packetType, sourceaddr = SA, destaddr = DA, packetsubtype = packetSubType }); }
 class test
   {
       public int sno { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string sourceaddr { get; set; }
       public string destaddr { get; set; }
       public string Bssid { get; set; }
       public string packetsubtype { get; set; }
       public UInt16 QOS { get; set; }
       public UInt16 duration { get; set; }
       public UInt16 seqcon { get; set; }
   }
```

thanks,

Comment: What are you doing which triggers `OutofMemoryException`? Without code, your question is unanswerable. You can use a good memory profiler to find where the memory leak is(in case it is a leak)

Comment: Following on from Sriram's comments, please provide some code. How are you updating your grid - are you just continually appending data to it ? Are you using databinding and have you enabled EnableRowVirtualization ?

Answer (score 0):

At some point you need to stop adding data and remove (aggregate and persist) older data.

By setting max number of *hot* data rows, you can limit amount of memory used by your app.

Comment: I am tried like this, I kept a limit for 50000 rows. if new row excceds 50000 rows then I am removing one row and adding one row using Items.RemoveAt(0). But the usage of Ram is not stopping